# Why does Pysnmp save bytes as strings in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, pysnmp

I'm trying to use `val.prettyPrint()` in Python 3.4.2 using Pysnmp 4.3.1 to read the values of the OIDs. `val.prettyPrint()` returns a string for any type of variable. So I receive this value `"b'zeus.snmplabs.com'"` as of type string instead of type bytes. So when I send this data to a server, it treats the `b` prefix as part of the string. Is this a bug or functionality intentional?

Comment: That looks like `repr` output, what is `val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug (actually, in pyasn1), however [development pysnmp code](http://pysnmp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pysnmp/pysnmp/?view=tar) has a workaround in place.

Keep in mind that in SNMP (and ASN.1) OCTET STRING type is supposed to carry bytes, not text. Therefore .prettyPrint() tries to represent value as printable 7-bit ASCII string if possible. Otherwise it switches to hex representation (0xdeadbeef).

SNMP objects that should carry text are usually explicitly typed as TEXTUAL-CONVENTION objects in MIBs. Based on MIB information SNMP manager would "cast"  protocol-level OCTET STRING values into a printable in specified encoding (ASCII or UTF-8) ignoring all non-printable characters along the way.